# How to launch XBMC from XBOX 360 controller guide button on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, kodi, game-controller

How can you configure the XBox 360 controller guide button to launch XBMC?

I am using XBMC Frodo RC3 on Windows 7 64bit, my controller is a wired one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to use [Guidecall](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=164695).

Once installed, you have to execute `C:\Program Files (x86)\GuideCall\Guidecall.exe` and let its windows opened while you use XBMC (you can minimize it).

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need a button-mapping program for the controller, such as [Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/) or [JoyToKey](http://www-en.jtksoft.net/).

Refer to the manual for whichever program you choose for instructions on mapping the `Guide` key to run the executable `XBMC.exe`.

Comment: Xpadder does not recognize the Guide button. Plus the softwares you mention are not free.

Comment: JoyToKey does not offer ability to launch a program when a button is pressed. My question is all about the ability to launch or focus XBMC with the guide button of the XBOX 360 controller.